# How to test a Magento SOAP API call using Postman

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v1, postman

Does anyone have a step by step tutorial on how to post and test a soap v1 api call using Postman?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use SOAP UI for testing the Magento 1 SOAP API and Postman or Swagger for Magento 2 Rest Calls. With SOAP UI you can import the full WSDL Schema with Basic Example Requests.

Download:

> https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html

How to use Steps:

- Click on SOAP or File > New SOAP Project(Create new SOAP project)
- Fill in a Project Name
- Fill in the wsdl schema url
- Press OK and now the schema will be imported
- Open the schema and go to the login call
- Open the login call and double click on Request 1
- Fill in you username and API key
- Run the API call by pressing the run icon
- Now you will retrieve an API-token which you can use for the other requests

Example of a WSDL schema URL:

> https://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1